# Unable to hide days field in jquery datebox durationbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, datebox

I have a jquery datebox plugin and i am using durationbox.I want to hide the "days" field from the durationbox so that it only display hours,minutes and seconds.I have tried "overrideDurationOrder":["h","i"] code but it doesnt worked.Is this possible ?
Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: whenever you are asking a question regarding thirdparty plugin, add the link to the respective site else its really hard to figure out whats happening. Also mention the version of scripts which you are using.

Comment: also, when including versions, please include the version of DateBox *and* the version of jQueryMobile.  If you can, a jsFiddle would not be a bad thing either.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your question is somewhat unclear - in order to hide the Days element in the **control**, something like this will do the trick:

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="lang1">yep</label>
    <input name="lang1" type="text" data-role="datebox"
      data-datebox-mode="durationbox" id="lang1"
      data-options='{"overrideDurationOrder": ["h","i","s"]}' />
</div>
```

If you do not want days mentioned in the **returned** data either, you will need to override the output format as well:

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="lang1">yep</label>
    <input name="lang1" type="text" data-role="datebox"
      data-datebox-mode="durationbox" id="lang1"
      data-options='{"overrideDurationOrder": ["h","i","s"],
        "overrideDurationFormat":"%Dl:%DM:%DS" }' />
</div>
```

Finally, if you meant that the labels on the control were incorrect, indeed - I just found that bug and corrected it.  Features tested and verified working on jQM 1.4.5, with DateBox 1.4.5